# Using vertex buffers in jogl, crash when too many triangles

Tags: opengl, jogl, vbo

I have written a simple application in Java using Jogl which draws a 3d geometry. The camera can be rotated by dragging the mouse. The application works fine, but drawing the geometry with glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE) ... calls ist too slow.

So I started to use vertex buffers. This also works fine until the number of triangles gets larger than 1000000. If that happens, the display driver suddenly crashes and my montior gets dark. Is there a limit of how many triangles fit in the buffer? I hoped to get 1000000 triangles rendered at a reasonable frame rate.

I have no idea on how to debug this problem. The nasty thing is that I have to reboot Windows after each launch, since I have no other way to get my display working again. Could anyone give me some advice?

The vertices, triangles and normals are stored in arrays float[][] m_vertices, int[][] m_triangles, float[][] m_triangleNormals.
I initialized the buffer with:

```
        // generate a VBO pointer / handle
        if (m_vboHandle <= 0) {
            int[] vboHandle = new int[1];
            m_gl.glGenBuffers(1, vboHandle, 0);
            m_vboHandle = vboHandle[0];
        }

        // interleave vertex / normal data
        FloatBuffer data = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(m_triangles.length * 3*3*2);
        for (int t=0; t<m_triangles.length; t++)
            for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
                int v = m_triangles[t][j];
                data.put(m_vertices[v]);
                data.put(m_triangleNormals[t]);
            }
        data.rewind();

        // transfer data to VBO
        int numBytes = data.capacity() * 4;
        m_gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboHandle);
        m_gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numBytes, data, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        m_gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Then, the scene gets rendered with:

```
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboHandle);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 6*4, 0);
        gl.glNormalPointer(GL.GL_FLOAT, 6*4, 3*4);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3*m_triangles.length);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: are you only drawing this one vertex/normal array? or is there other stuff going on in your scene...

Answer (score 3):

Try checking the return value of calling `glBufferData`.  It will return `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` if it cannot satisfy `numBytes`.

Comment: sorry, i should clarify this answer.  glBufferData doesn't "return" GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY.  instead it "generates" the error.  You can get the error by calling glGetError() after calling glBufferData()

Comment: I have checked the error code. It is 0 (no error) after the glBufferData() call. I have made an additional observation: The display driver does not crash immediately (the first frames are rendered fine), but if I try to zoom in into the scene. Maybe there is an internal overflow when too many triangles are rendered which are too large in size?

Comment: hmm are your drivers up to date?  the fact that it is *crashing* indicates something's not right with the driver, or possibly even the hardware.  Have you tried it on another computer?

Comment: it may also help to put the triangles into separate array buffers, and draw them with multiple glDrawArray calls -- see if that helps